# htaccess - how to fix this rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

This is our current rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^share/([A-z0-9]+)[/{0,1}]?/([A-z0-9]+)[/{0,1}]?$ /mods/share/video.php?video=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```

Basically, if I visit:

```
http://www.site.com/share/f7Hje-xxGf/fio2fh92fh9bfh
```

The page displays a 404 error.

If I remove the `-` from inbetween the first rewrite, it works fine.

I guess it isn't allowing symbols, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^share/([A-z0-9]+)[/{0,1}]?/([A-z0-9]+)[/{0,1}]?$ /mods/share/video.php?video=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```

adding - to the character-match

```
RewriteRule ^share/([A-z0-9-]+)[/{0,1}]?/([A-z0-9-]+)[/{0,1}]?$ /mods/share/video.php?video=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```

cleaning the thing up

```
RewriteRule ^share/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /mods/share/video.php?video=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```